# How to implement sleep for webpage?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I tried

```
WScript.Sleep 5000 'sleep for 5 seconds
```

But the above code doesn't work with webpages, it works fine with `.vbs` files.

I tried like below code also, it waits but the webpage stays busy:

```
Dim waitTime
waitTime = DateAdd("s", 5, Now())
Do Until (Now() > waitTime)
Loop
```

Is there a better way to pause the script for sometime when working from webpages?

Comment: You can divide the script functionality and use the `window.setTimeout` method to call the next step in the script when the indicated timeout has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

The Scripting Guy! Blog has an [example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/03/30/how-can-i-temporarily-pause-a-script-in-an-hta.aspx) of how to use `window.setTimeout` in an HTA. It should work the same way in a "regular" web page.

```
<script language="VBScript">
  Dim dtmStartTime

  Sub Test
    dtmStartTime = Now 
    idTimer = window.setTimeout("PausedSection", 5000, "VBScript")
  End Sub

  Sub PausedSection
    'do stuff here
    window.clearTimeout(idTimer)
  End Sub
</script>
```